# Center a CFormView "dialog resource" within the CMainFrame window in a SDI

Tags: mfc, sdi

I have a dialog resource with some controls inside, mostly a user and password edit controls, bonded to a `CFormView`. Such dialog is a small rectangle of 300 x 200 pixels.

When I run the application, the `CFrameWindow` occupies almost all screen, so the dialog shows in top-left corner. If I try to get the rectangle dimension of `CFormView`, I found that it has been expanded to visible area in `CMainFrame`, no matter the original dialog size.

[image: What I currently get]

My question is whether is possible to keep the dialog (the `CFormView`) centred in the middle of the `CMainFrame`, and keep always centred even if the `ON_SIZE` message is called.

[image: What I want]

Thank you.

Comment: I just did a quick search and see several. Eg: https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/article.php/c3765/Automatically-Center-the-Controls-in-CFormView.htm But I have no personal experience with this. What about adjusting the dynamic layout properties of the controls in the resource editor?

Comment: I'd suggest that's not the desired solution. Better would be to make the frame smaller, and then center it. This answer shows how to make the frame smaller: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940927/how-does-one-resize-the-formdialog-in-a-mfc-sdi-cformview-application

Comment: Probably in overriding RecalcLayout() in your frame class is where you want to intercept this. Working from memory here...and don't have a VC++ on this machine...but, the frame gets the view and resizes it to be the same size as the frame client area (well, close--area reserved for view after toolbars, etc, taken care of). You could have the formview be a child of another window and have that window center the formview. For instance, splitter windows are the child of the frame, and then views are children of the splitter window.

Comment: You don't have to write any line of code. Just use the dynamic layout capabilities in VS2019 rc editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS2019 you don't have to write any line of code. The rc Editor has the dynamic layout function capabilities. Place the controls exactly in the middle of the dialog. Then set the

[image]